# How to open a bathroom Florescent fixture?

Tags: bathroom, light-fixture

My 4-foot bathroom florescent light is flickering, so I bought new LED tubes.  But I found out that I don't know how to open the thing.  There doesn't seem to be anything to press, the cover doesn't twist or anything, and the ends don't pull off.  There doesn't seem to be tabs anywhere either.  Not sure where to start looking or what to push.  Any ideas?  below is a picture of the end of the fixture, sorry for the quality, but the light is flickering pretty badly.

[image: end of the halogen fixture in question]

Comment: Are you sure that's halogen? From the part shown, it looks like a florescent light. Also, halogens don't blink (at least not on their own) while old fluorescents do. You should try to get a better photo. Suggest you turn off the light and use your camera/phone's flash.

Comment: Oops, I meant florescent.  The long tube thingys.  I'll try and get a better picture when I get home tonight.

Comment: Many of those fixture covers will release if you depress them slightly along one side where the plastic tucks into the fixture housing. Be careful, the plastic gets brittle over time and you will probably not be able to procure a replacement.

Comment: Oops, meant to close this out earlier.  While taking better pictures, I found a previously unseen indent on the side. sticking a screwdriver in and prying popped open the end cap.  The cover slides out easily after that.